# How to use Client for NFS on Windows Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, network-shares, nfs, drive-letter

I've installed "Client for NFS" on my 32-bit Windows Vista Ultimate.  However, I can't find it in the start menu, and can't find any documentation on how to use it.

1. How do I connect to a NFS share using "Client for NFS"?
2. Can I map it to a drive letter?
3. How do I choose connection options, such as my uid/gid, mount as read-only, port number, etc?

Ideally I would like to map a NFS share using the command line.

You may also suggest alternatives to "Client for NFS".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Windows 7, I can use the mount command:

mount host:/folder x:

where folder represents the full path from root to the NFS shared folder.

Answer (score 1):

It can be very awkward, personally, I just look through network or access the machine like I would a Windows machine and the NFS shares should show up like a standard Windows one. You should then have the standard options such as mount to a letter.

For number 3, I am honestly not to sure but would of thought these were set server side.

(... For the last part, you should be able to use the mount command... I can't get to my NFS box to verify so not 100% sure.)

Comment: For Windows share, you would do `mount \\host\share X:`.  What is the syntax for mounting NFS share? (if it can be done with mount)

Answer (score 1):

When I had installed *Windows Services for UNIX Version 3.5* I had the same idea. Reading the previous post I also checked the server at the network in Windows Explorer by typing in \servername

Only the Samba shares (a Linux server in my case) showed up here. I noticed however that below *My Network Places*, a new item showed up named *NFS Network*. Browsing that I could see (and map) my NFS shares.