# NFS under Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, nfs

How to add a NFS device under Windows Vista?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to have either Vista Business or Ultimate then:

> Go to Control Panel / Programs and Features
>   / Turn Windows features on or off, it
>   shows "Services for NFS" with two
>   choices; "Administrative Tools" and
>   "Client for NFS"

Not sure what you need to do after you've got it installed, but [this](http://www.vistax64.com/vista-networking-sharing/40707-nfs-server-how-get-nfs-share-vista.html) suggests it should just "work"...

Aha, search is your friend: [How to use Client for NFS on Windows Vista?](https://superuser.com/questions/98915/how-to-use-client-for-nfs-on-windows-vista)

Comment: Nice answer dude!